# What do these VS Code template strings mean?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've installed the [File Templates for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bam.vscode-file-templates) extension in order to create new templates.  When I create a new HTML template, there are strings in the <title> and <body> elements that I don't recognize.  I know I can just delete them and insert my own title and body content but I'm wondering what they do.  Can I set variables someplace so that default title and body content will be inserted whenever I create a new HTML template?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="author" content="John Doe">
        <title>#[[$Title$]]#</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        #[[$END$]]#
    </body>

    </html>
```

---

---

Answer (score 0):

That extension hasn't been updated for 3 years.

The 2 fields you mention are probably features that where meant to be implemented in a new version but the code has no mentioning of this.

I have written a replacement that fixed a number of problems and added a few features: [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates).

The HTML template is now:

```
<!-- ******************************************
*  Author : ${author}
*  Created On : ${dateTimeFormat}
*  File : ${fileBasename}
******************************************* -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="author" content="${author}"/>
  <title>${input#Title#}</title>
</head>

<body>
  ${cursor}
</body>

</html>
```